# Search string which contains specail characters(!,@,#./,comma(,))

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in DB where it may contain data with special characters.
for ex:a column,Name may have data as following
santosh's
santosh/s
santosh%s

How to search for these values in DB using like operator.

```
Select * from table where name like '%santosh%';
```

How to change the above query to search for apostrophe(santosh's)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for 1. apostrophe s  you can use

```
Select * from table where column like '%santosh''s%'
```

for 2. /s you can give directly

```
Select * from table where column like '%santosh/s%'
```

for 3. %s you can use

```
Select * from table where column like '%santosh[%]s%'
```

hope this helps.....

Comment: here table is your table name column is your column name

Answer (score 0):

Just use 2 apostrophe to escape the character

```
Select * from table where name like '%santosh''s%';
```

Comment: how about with stored Procedure.If i pass this a parameter to the storeprocedure. select name from table where name like '%+vvcrSearch+%'.where vvcrSearch is the parameter.I cant keep 2 apostrophe every time as the column data may or may not contain apostrophe or some other special characters